# How to Open .DAT file Extension ,Download from Biometrics to usb

Tags: vb.net, vb6, biometrics

how to open .DAT file extension ,Downloaded from Biometrics to Usb.. so that i can see the time attendance of the employee from the usb.. bcause last time i download the all files(Time attendance of the employee) from the Biometrics and i use flashdrive to save all the files.. and when i insert my flashdrive into my PC all i have .. is the ( AFP_001.DAT ) How can i see it or Open it in the right format? 
Here's my files :
http://www.4shared.com/file/HwF4p26Aba/AFP_001.html?sop=true

Comment: is this a programming question or is this spam?

Comment: NO... this is a Question.. whY dont you tried first! how to open the file i attached on that !

Comment: There is no standard way to open a DAT file because it's not a "standard" file type.  The ".dat" file extension simply means a data file and many different applications use DAT files with many different formats.  You need to go back to the supplier/manufacturer of your device and found out what the format is and, if there isn't an API already, write some custom code to read the data in that format.  That might involve reading text using a `StreamReader` or binary data using a `FileStream` or something else. It all depends on the actual data format.